# Can GNOME crash my computer?

Tags: ubuntu

I've been having this problem for several weeks now: from time to time my computer freezes, the desktop loses all the icons and the HD light goes on. Most of the time this gets solved by waiting 2-5 minutes, but sometimes there's no other choice than rebooting

By opening a new terminal, I get the following message (more or less, since I don't have my laptop with me right now):

```
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }, exception Emask 0×0 SAct 0×0 SErr 0×0 action 0×0
```

OR

```
failed (errno=-16)
```

(the latter usually meaning that I have to reboot the computer)

The funny thing is that when I'm on a terminal none of this happens (I can listen to music, compile applications, browse the Internet, etc)

So, my question is: can this be happening because of GNOME or more likely it's a HD failure?

BTW, I'm running Ubuntu (¡please don't punch me!) 9.10 .

Comment: You'll get better responses on SuperUser.

Comment: I didn't know about SuperUser, just StackOverflow and Serverfault, ¡thanks for migrating the question to this site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say but to me it sounds like a hardware problem. Can you reliably reproduce this? Is there a list of steps that *always* cause this? If no to both of these, then I would be *very* certain it's a hardware failure.

Comment: This usually happens when it has to display several folders+archives with Nautilus. That's the only one I can reproduce that whilst is not 100% sure going to trigger the issue, it does most of the time.

 I too, thought it was a hardware problem, though I had the wishful thinking it would be something with the GUI (because if it is the HD, I'll have to backup all the 500GiB which is a pain in the ass)

Comment: @Gastón: Hmm well that's a little more consistent, but sometimes a minor hardware issue can be agravated by certain software. Have you tried testing for problems on the harddrive? You could also try mirroring to a new hard drive and see if booting from the new drive gives problems in the same situation.

Comment: The only thing I've tried is doing fsck, which found the first time some corrupted nodes and nothing later. I will buy a HD next week (backup my stuff there) and run a couple of tests.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a hard drive problem to me.  Maybe GNOME is triggering it because it uses stuff on the bad part of the drive.